# DSolve gets stuck on system of differential equations with unassigned variable

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, symbolic

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem. I'm running a fairly simple script that involves some matrix operations and ends with a fairly nasty system of differential equations:

```
h2 = {{0, -(Ω/2)}, {-(Ω/2), -k v + Δ}}

ρ = {{ρ11[t], ρ12[t]}, {ρ21[t], ρ22[t]}}

ρprime = -I (h2.ρ - ρ.h2) + {{1/2 γ ρ22[t], -γ ρ12[t]}, {-γ ρ21[t], -(1/2) γ ρ22[t]}}

replace3 = {Δ -> 0.1, γ -> 1, Ω -> 0.1, k -> 0.1}; 

p3 = DSolve[{ρ11'[t] == ρprime[[1, 1]], ρ12'[t] == ρprime[[1, 2]], 
             ρ21'[t] == ρprime[[2, 1]], ρ22'[t] == ρprime[[2, 2]], 
             ρ11[0] == 1, ρ22[0] == 0, ρ12[0] == 0, ρ21[0] == 0} /. replace3, 
            {ρ11[t], ρ12[t], ρ21[t], ρ22[t]}, {t}]
```

Basically, I'm trying to solve a system of four differential equations analytically, with one variable, `v`, left unassigned. It is very important that `v` not be assigned a value as this point in the script. However, when I run it, it gets stuck on the `DSolve` part and can't seem to do it. When I first assign `v` a value and then run it, the `DSolve` works fine. Is this system of equations simply to complicated to be solved analytically? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: For some web browsers you can install an add-on that lets you format the Greek letters.  See the answer to [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) for  information.

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste the code directly from Mathematica. Please do that - nobody is going to copy your code down from the image :)

Comment: Edit: Added code.

Comment: You may be able to simplify the system by using the fact that $\rho_{11}+\rho_{22}$ is a constant and $\rho_{12}+\rho_{21}$ is another constant.  The initial conditions provide the values of the constants.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved with `LaplaceTransform` in about 10 seconds:

```
h2 = {{0, -Ω/2}, {-Ω/2, -k v + Δ}};
ρ = {{ρ11[t], ρ12[t]}, {ρ21[t], ρ22[t]}};
ρprime = -I (h2.ρ - ρ.h2) + {{1/2 γ ρ22[t], -γ ρ12[t]}, {-γ ρ21[t], -1/2 γ ρ22[t]}};
replace3 = {Δ -> 1/10, γ -> 1, Ω -> 1/10, k -> 1/10};

var = Flatten@ρ;

{eq, ic} = {D[var, t] == Flatten@ρprime // Thread, 
            var == {1, 0, 0, 0} /. t -> 0 // Thread} /. replace3

tvar = LaplaceTransform[var, t, s];
tsol = tvar /. First@Solve[LaplaceTransform[eq, t, s] /. Rule @@@ ic, tvar] // Simplify

(sol = InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol, s, t]) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {10.324655, ……} *)
```

The result involves `Roots`, if you don't like it, just add a `ToRadicals`.

Comment: would it be possible to use this method to implicitly plot the equation `v=b-t ρ11[t]` , where `b` is a constant and `ρ11[t]` is a solution to the system that depends on `t` and `v`?

Comment: @CalebHorwitz It's another question that can be solved with `ContourPlot`, isn't it?

Comment: I've tried running `ρsol22 = Simplify[sol[[2, 2]], {v > 0, t > 0}];` followed by `ContourPlot[v == 10^3 - t Re[ρsol22], {t, 0, 10}, {v, 0, 10^3}]`, but nothing comes up on the plot. Why?

Comment: @CalebHorwitz Use e.g. `{v, 0, 2 10^3}` instead.

Comment: in generalizing this script to higher dimensions, is there any way to speed up the computation? I tried using a similar method with 3x3 matrices, and it won't seem to finish.

Comment: @CalebHorwitz That really depends. Please add the specific code to the question, or ask a new question if the sample is largely different from the current one.

Comment: I posted a new question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206891/help-speeding-up-solution-of-system-of-differential-equations-using-laplace-tran)

Comment: @xzcd would this method work for solving nonlinear coupled systems of equations?

Comment: @cal  No, Laplace transform is not magic. For more info please check the property of Laplace transform carefully.