# Solving system of differential equations in loop with recursive variable

Tags: differential-equations, backslide

**Backslide introduced in 11.3, fixed in 12.0.**

---

I've been posting various questions about similar pieces of code all year, so if this looks familiar you may have seen another one of my posts, but this is a unique issue that has not been asked yet, so I am posting it here. Basically I am using a loop so solve a system of coupled differential equations, using those results to change the value of a variable accordingly, then solve the system again, this time with the new value of the variable that was changed, and I want to do this in small steps 200 times, then plot the output. Here is the code:

```
h2 = {{0, -(Ω/2)}, {-(Ω/2), δ0 + Δ}};

ρ2 = {{ρ11[t], ρ12[t]}, {ρ21[t], ρ22[t]}};

ρdecay = {{1/2*γ*ρ22[t], -γ*ρ12[t]}, {-γ*ρ21[t], -(1/2)*γ*ρ22[t]}};

ρtderiv = -I*(h2.ρ2 - ρ2.h2) + ρdecay;

replace3 = {Δ -> -1*10^9, γ -> 1.6*10^9, Ω -> 1, m -> 10^-25, ℏ -> 1*10^-34, k -> (2 π)/(500*10^-9), v -> 10^3};

txvarray = Table[{0, 0, 0}, 200];

t0 = 0; ρ120 = 0; ρ210 = 0; ρ220 = 0; ρ110 = 1; δ0 = (2 π*10^3)/(500*10^-9);

Do[{ρsol11, ρsol12, ρsol21, ρsol22} = NDSolveValue[{ρ11'[t] == ρtderiv[[1, 1]], ρ12'[t] == ρtderiv[[1, 2]], ρ21'[t] == ρtderiv[[2, 1]], ρ22'[t] == ρtderiv[[2, 2]], ρ11[t0] == ρ110, ρ12[t0] == ρ120, ρ21[t0] == ρ210, ρ22[t0] == ρ220} /. replace3, {ρ11, ρ12, ρ21, ρ22}, {t, t0, t0 + 0.01}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
Δt = 0.01;
t0 += Δt;
fscatt = ℏ k^2 γ Re[ρsol22[t0]]/m /. replace3;
δ0 -= Δt fscatt;
txvarray[[i, 1]] = t0;
txvarray[[i, 2]] = fscatt;
txvarray[[i, 3]] = δ0;
ρ120 = ρsol12[t0];
ρ210 = ρsol21[t0];
ρ220 = ρsol22[t0];
ρ110 = ρsol11[t0], {i, 1, 200}]

txabs = Table[{txvarray[[i, 1]], Abs[txvarray[[i, 3]]]}, {i, 1, 200}];

ListPlot[txabs, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

Note the `δ0` in the first line, in `h2`. This is the variable that changes after each iteration (this happens in the line `δ0 -= Δt fscatt;`). The problem is that whenever I try to run this code, it gets stuck and I have to quit the kernal. Any ideas why this is happening/how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in _v9.0.1_ and _v11.2_. (in _v9.0.1_ the definition of `txvarray` should be `txvarray = Table[{0, 0, 0}, {200}];`) though. ) Have you `Clear`ed the variables before executing the code? (Especially `δ0`.) Please double check the sample.

Comment: So you're saying it executes fine in v9.0.1 and 11.2? I have tried clearing all variables with this script, but I get the same result.

Comment: Please check if you've posted the correct sample here.

Comment: A general comment. I suggest breaking up your code into smaller pieces which makes checking the pieces easier. Also use `Print[]` statements to track the progress of evaluation.

Comment: @xzczd this is definitely the correct sample. I just tried running it with cleared variables again, and I even copy-pasted the code from this post into a new notebook just to see if I messed up.

Comment: @Somos I will try that asap, although i'm not sure how because everything is already split into individual cells, with the Do loop in it's own cell, and i'm not sure what in that loop I can print.

Comment: Well, copying into a new notebook doesn't make any difference, because everything is stored in the same kernel by default. Have you tried restarting your _Mathematica_?

Comment: I have tried restarting it. I'm curious, what does the output look like that you are getting?

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. The output I got is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ez3Xj.png

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Just tested on Wolfram cloud, the sample no longer gets stuck in *v12.0*.

---

OK, I manage to reproduce the issue in *v11.3*, but not in *v11.2* and *v9*. I guess this is related to the truth that [`"CatchMachineUnderflow"` option is removed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56729/1871) in this version, because after adding `WorkingPrecision -> 16` to `NDSolveValue` together with `Rationalize[..., 0]`, the problem is resolved:

```
h2 = {{0, -(Ω/2)}, {-(Ω/2), δ0 + Δ}};   
ρ2 = {{ρ11[t], ρ12[t]}, {ρ21[t], ρ22[t]}};

ρdecay = {{1/2*γ*ρ22[t], -γ*ρ12[t]}, {-γ*ρ21[t], -(1/2)*γ*ρ22[t]}};

ρtderiv = -I*(h2.ρ2 - ρ2.h2) + ρdecay;

replace3 = {Δ -> -1*10^9, γ -> 1.6*10^9, Ω -> 1, 
   m -> 10^-25, ℏ -> 1*10^-34, k -> (2 π)/(500*10^-9), v -> 10^3};

txvarray = Table[{0, 0, 0}, 200];

t0 = 0; ρ120 = 0; ρ210 = 0; ρ220 = 0; ρ110 = 1; δ0 = (2 π*10^3)/(500*10^-9);

Do[{ρsol11, ρsol12, ρsol21, ρsol22} = 
  NDSolveValue[{ρ11'[t] == ρtderiv[[1, 1]], ρ12'[
        t] == ρtderiv[[1, 2]], ρ21'[t] == ρtderiv[[2, 1]], ρ22'[
        t] == ρtderiv[[2, 2]], ρ11[t0] == ρ110, ρ12[
        t0] == ρ120, ρ21[t0] == ρ210, ρ22[t0] == ρ220} /. 
     replace3 // Rationalize[#, 0] &, {ρ11, ρ12, ρ21, ρ22}, {t, t0, 
    t0 + 0.01}, WorkingPrecision -> 16];
 Δt = 0.01;
 t0 += Δt;
 fscatt = ℏ k^2 γ Re[ρsol22[t0]]/m /. replace3;
 δ0 -= Δt fscatt;
 txvarray[[i, 1]] = t0;
 txvarray[[i, 2]] = fscatt;
 txvarray[[i, 3]] = δ0;
 ρ120 = ρsol12[t0];
 ρ210 = ρsol21[t0];
 ρ220 = ρsol22[t0];
 ρ110 = ρsol11[t0], {i, 1, 200}]

txabs = Table[{txvarray[[i, 1]], Abs[txvarray[[i, 3]]]}, {i, 1, 200}];

ListPlot[txabs, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

The output is just the same as in *v9* and *v11.2*:

*v11.3 result after adding `WorkingPrecision -> 16`:*

[image]

*v9 result (Definition of `txvarray` is modified to `txvarray = Table[{0, 0, 0}, {200}]`):*

[image]

Comment: It works in machine precision for me if I only rationalize the equations.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Which version are you in? In v11.3, Win 7 64bit, `WorkingPrecision->16` is necessary, or `mxst` warning pops up and the kernel crashes. `Rationalize[..., 0]` isn't necessary, though `precw` warning will pop up, the result is the same.

Comment: `"11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 22, 2018)"` -- Note the date: the most recent microversion is from March 2018, I think.  For some reason, I can't download it from the user portal.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Indeed, mine is `"11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 27, 2018)"`.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! This appears to have fixed the issue of the kernal crashing. However, how do I know for certain that it is doing what I want, i.e. how do I know it is in fact using the new value of `δ0` and not the first one assigned earlier in the script?

Comment: @CalebHorwitz Well, the code is correctly written, as far as I can tell, so the new value should have been used. This answer is also in accordance with the analytic solution in [your early question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179209/1871). If the solution should not be a line that's seemingly horizon to $t$ axis, then you should double check the underlying model. (Notice the value of `Δt fscatt` is very small compared to `δ0`, is it normal? )

Comment: @xzczd , an update: when I use very large values for `Ω`, such as `Ω->10^8`, I get a few error messages, including "Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t==....". This is very similar to what was happening before.

Comment: @CalebHorwitz This is probably the nature of the solution, just increase `Ω` slowly and observe the resulting graphic. As already mentioned in my last comment, if the result is not desired, you'd better double check the underlying model.